# Storing values to init but it keeps overwriting the list when a new file read

Tags: python, init, self

I have two files and load into the class. File one is loaded and then create a string, then file two will load and create a string again and lastly both in one list. However, when I call the function, it just keep overwriting by the new file. Example, When file 2 is read then it only create strings for file 2 and overwrite file 1.

```
    class something():
    def getting(self, y):# string input "0" and "1"
        self.y = y #I have two files. y is a file. So if I have 2 files, then it will store 2 times into the self.y. Example, file one have "0" and "1" string
        self.fun1()

    def fun1(self):
        self.xx = []
        for i in range(2):
            self.xx.append("{} and {}".format(self.y, i)) #After getting the self.y, then it will append it into self.xx.
            # Example, 0 and 0 then 0 and 1; for y in "0" string.
            # Next, 1 and 0 then 1 and 1; for y in "1" string
            self.take()

    def take(self):
        return self.xx



a = ["0", "1"]
aaa = something()
for x in a:

    aaa.getting(x)

print(aaa.take())
```

Current output:

```
['1 and 0', '1 and 1']
```

Expected for the a.take:

```
['0 and 0', '0 and 1', '1 and 0', '1 and 1']
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated, please check

Comment: Newly edited with current output and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an older post:

I think you are overloading the variable 'a' in the following piece of code.  By the time you are done with first iteration of the for loop, a has been changed with the code inside the loop.  You must instead use another variable to track your list (something()).

```
a = ["0", "1"]
for x in a:
    a = something()
    a.getting(x)

    print(a.take)
```

Try this:

```
a = ["0", "1"]
b = something()
for x in a:  
    b.getting(x)
    print(b.take)
```

Answer for the updated post:

You are resetting self.xx in fun1(). What you must do is set self.xx to [] in the init function of something(). And, don't set self.xx to [] at start of fun1()

Comment: Yea, I have already updated it and the current post is the newest with current and expected outputs

Comment: I wish to have my expected output. Somehow it output 2 files differently, I wish it to be in one list.

Comment: You are resetting self.xx in fun1().  What you must do is set self.xx to [] in the __init__ function of something().  And, don't set self.xx to [] at start of fun1().

Comment: Please update your answer so that I could mark it as answer

Comment: Updated the answer.  Can you please mark it now?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Original Question:**

The `__init__` method is only called on the objects creation.
For example:

```
o = something()
```

Will create an instance of the class `something` (and store it as `o`) and execute the `__init__` method.

Further method (other) calls, such as your `getting` method, on the object `o` will not re-execute the `__init__` method.

A possible solution would be to move the code where you append to the list to the method you are calling:

```
class something():
    def __init__(self): 
        self.xx = []

    def getting(self, y):
        for i in range(2):
            self.xx.append("{} and {}".format(y, i))

o = something()

o.getting("0")
o.getting("1")

print(o.xx)
```

This gives the output you have described, however I am not totally sure what you trying to achieve. I would also recommend using alternative variable/method/class names, having names which describe their function aids in human readability.

**Edit 2:**
You are still overwriting a number of variables, try:

```
class something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xx = []

    def getting(self, y):# string input "0" and "1"
        self.y = y #I have two files. y is a file. So if I have 2 files, then it will store 2 times into the self.y. Example, file one have "0" and "1" string
        self.fun1()

    def fun1(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.xx.append("{} and {}".format(self.y, i)) #After getting the self.y, then it will append it into self.xx.
            # Example, 0 and 0 then 0 and 1; for y in "0" string.
            # Next, 1 and 0 then 1 and 1; for y in "1" string

    def take(self):
        return self.xx



a = ["0", "1"]
aaa = something()
for x in a:
    aaa.getting(x)

print(aaa.take())
```

Comment: I already updated my code. Is it not possible to have the value in def take(self) to return something like the expected output?

Comment: @TryingThisSite the method `take(self)` should be fine, you have other issues, namely you are overwriting the object each loop as well as it being the variable you are looping over

Comment: Actually, i just updated it again. I mistype the variables just now